# can't figure out how to make iframe full width

Tags: css, iframe

our site has a max width that i cannot figure out how to override.  i'm guessing because of a div/container.  i'm not a developer so i'm not sure where to look.  i've tried !important but that hasn't worked.  i created a block and inserted that block on a category page.

[here's the page](http://questjewelers.com/wedding/verragio)

I've tried this solution but didn't work since it's limited by the container?

```
<div class="main col1-layout">...</div>

Try using .main.col1-layout {float:none; width:100%; padding-top:0px;}
```

Comment: Please post your code or this will be deleted. It is impossible to assist you with what you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want full width website you can use this code at bottom of the style-sheet to override `.row {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.large-12 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}`

And the outpuut looks like this
 [image]